# Change the structure of ElasticSearch response json

Tags: elasticsearch

In some cases, I don't need all of the fields in response json.

For example,

```
// request json
{
  "_source": "false",
  "aggs": { ... },
  "query": { ... }
}

// response json
{
  "took": 123,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": { ... },
  "hits": {
    "total": 123,
    "max_score": 123,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "foo",
        "_type": "bar",
        "_id": "123",
        "_score": 123
      }
    ],
    ...
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "foo": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 123,
          "doc_count": 123
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Actually I don't need the `_index`/`_type` every time. When I do aggregations, I don't need `hits` block.

`"_source" : false` or `"_source": { "exclude": [ "foobar" ] }` can help ignore/exclude the `_source` fields in `hits` block.

But can I change the structure of ES response json in a more common way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to "slim down" the Elasticsearch response as it was well over 1MB in json and I started using the [filter_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) request variable.
This allows to include or exclude specific fields and can have different types of wildcards.  Do read the docs in the link above as there is quite some info there.

eg.

```
_search?filter_path=aggregations.**.hits._source,aggregations.**.key,aggregations.**.doc_count
```

This reduced (in my case) the response size by half without significantly increasing the search duration, so well worth the effort..

Answer (score 1):

In the `hits` section, you will always jave `_index`, `_type` and `_id` fields. If you want to retrieve only some specific fields in your search results, you can use `fields` parameter in the root object :

```
{
  "query": { ... },
  "aggs": { ... },
  "fields":["fieldName1","fieldName2", etc...]
}
```

When doing aggregations, you can use the `search_type` ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#count)) parameter with `count` value like this :

```
GET index/type/_search?search_type=count
```

It won't return any document but only the result count, and your aggregations will be computed in the exact same way.

Comment: I find `"size": 0` also works like `search_type=count`.

Comment: How about changing the structure?
Something like:
"fields":["fieldName1":{"fieldName2", etc...}]
Is this possible?

Comment: You won't be able to do directly in ElasticSearch : this have to be done on client side.